# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at store unit tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, store, ngrx-store

I can't solve this problem *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object* when I run unit tests. I don't know why I have got this error because data appear in subscribe. Can someone please help to fix it?

ts

```
locations$ = this.store.select((state: IAppState): Locations => state.locations.locations);
getLocations(): void {
this.store.dispatch(GetLocations({ reset: this.reset }));
console.log(this.locations$)
this.locations$(here is an error).subscribe((item) => {
  if (item) {
    const key = 'content';
    this.locations = Array.from(Object.values(item[key]));
    this.reset = false;
  }
});
}
```

spec.ts

```
    const storeMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('store', ['select', 'dispatch']);
    storeMock.select = () => of([fakeLocations] as any);
    beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MyComponent, 
        ...
      ],
      imports: [
        ...
      ],
      providers: [
        ...
        { provide: Store, useValue: storeMock }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
    }));
    beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UbsAdminTariffsLocationDashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this line:

```
storeMock.select = () => of([fakeLocations] as any);
```

is causing the issue.

You are accessing the locations from an object:

```
this.store.select((state: IAppState): Locations => state.locations.locations);
```

So I am thinking you would have to provide an object like so.

Try this:

```
// storeMock.select = () => of([fakeLocations] as any);
storeMock.select.and.returnValue(of({ locations: { locations: of[fakeLocations] } }));
```

I think with the above, we will be mocking `state.locations.locations` correctly.

**Edit**
I am thinking then this line is problematic:

```
if (item) {
    const key = 'content';
    // !! comment out below line and see if the error goes away
    //    this.locations = Array.from(Object.values(item[key]));
    this.reset = false;
  }
```

If the error goes away with the above line, then I am thinking `item[key]` is undefined or null and Object.values throws that error.

Comment: I have mocked `state.locations.locations` as you said but nothing changed.

Comment: Ok, check out my edit.

Comment: Yeah, item[key] is undefined and I don't khow why(

Comment: Maybe log both `item` and `key` and see their values. I think that will give you a better idea.